# Low rank approximation of matrix under $l_2$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Theorem 14 of [this](http:///http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/Staff/ukoethe/lehre/AlgorithmsForBigData/sarlos_06_matrix-approximation.pdf) paper by Tam´as Sarl´os gives a relative error rank-$k$ approximation of a given matrix $A$ under the [frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) norm. I am looking for reference of a similar result (relative error low rank approximation) under the $l_2$ norm.

Pls let me know I am  able to put the question clearly.

Comment: "$l_2$ norm" ​ = ​ "Euclidean [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm)" ​ ​ ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the median k-flat problem. Feldman wrote some papers on this and related problems. See for example  http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1379 .